# How can I switch an element from a vector to another in C++?

Tags: c++, dynamic, vector, cocos2d-x

Yesterday I started learning C++, so I'm pretty new at this. (I come from C#)
I'm trying to do a pool with two vectors (active and inactive), so when I need an element I take it from the inactive vector and put it in the active one.

I think I have to delete the pointer from the inactive but keep the element in memory, right?
How can I do this?

Here is what In have so far:

```
    SpritePool::SpritePool(const char *p)
{
    path = p;

}

CCSprite SpritePool::GetSprite(){
    while(poolVectorInactive.size == 0){
        AddSprite();
    }

}

CCSprite SpritePool::AddSprite(){
    CCSprite *s = CCSprite::create(path);
    poolVectorInactive.push_back(*s);
    return *s;

}
```

Comment: What's the definition and declaration of the vectors?

Comment: private:
 vector<CCSprite> poolVectorActive;

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

std::vector<CCSprite*>::iterator it = std::find_if(inactive.begin(), inactive.end(), [](CCSprite* sprite) { /* put your vector search logic (returning bool) here */ });
if (it != inactive.end())
{
    active.push_back(*it);
    inactive.erase(it);
    delete *it;
}
```

Note that it uses lambda-expressions (see e.g. http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-lambda-closures.html), so you'll need a C++11 compatible compiler. If you can't afford that luxury, write a function like:

```
bool matcher(CCSprite* sprite)
{
     /* code here */
}
```

and change this part:

```
std::vector<CCSprite*>::iterator it = std::find_if(inactive.begin(), inactive.end(), matcher);
```

Also, if you can, try to NOT use raw pointers. Store them in e.g. `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr`, so you don't have to handle deleting them manually. This will save you some leaks and headaches.

Comment: Cococ2d-x have own "automatic management system" called autorealease pool, and using shared pointer with CCObject (like CCSprite) isn't good idea.